# What are the rules followed by community user to review edit suggestions

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, community-user

Today I saw a [Suggested Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7815877) that was rejected by the [Community User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) . But I think that edit was OK. Later I saw that that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842848/join-one-table-multiple-times-in-mysql) was edited as it was suggested. I found this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) How it removes Questions.I would like to know How it review Suggested Edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rejection message, on the page of the edit suggestion, gives you the reason:

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

There was not necessarily anything wrong with that edit. There was simply someone else editing at the same time. And the other edit won out.

There is one other way in which Community User may reject an edit: when a reviewer selects "Reject and Edit" when reviewing an edit suggestion.
In this case, the original suggestion is automatically rejected by the Community User, and the reviewer's alternative edit is used instead.

In the post linked as duplicate, there is talk of "unchecking the 'this edit was helpful' box". This was an older system, where edit reviewers could improve an edit suggestion, then click a checkbox to say that the original edit was useful enough to be treated as an approval.
In the current system, when reviewers want to make their own edit, they must determine beforehand if the original edit deserves an approval.
If they choose "Improve", they improve the existing edit suggestion, and it counts as approval for the original editor.
If they choose "Reject and Edit", they have to edit the original post, and the Community User will reject the original suggestion.